# Start Command Line Program from Grails?

Tags: java, ubuntu, grails, groovy, grails-2.0

I have a Grails application, which has a cron job that should start a 
command line process.

I know that with Gradle I can easily start a command line process, but I do not know how I can do that with Grails.

**How can I start a command line process from my Grails/Groovy/Java application?**

Comment: `["tool", "params"].execute()` - what have you tried?  SO is full with answers to similar questions - what is different here?

Comment: @cfrick Could you please link any documentation for that?

Comment: http://groovy-lang.org/groovy-dev-kit.html#process-management

Comment: @cfrick If you post all your comments in an answer I will accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just be groovy http://groovy-lang.org/groovy-dev-kit.html#process-management:

```
["touch", "/var/tmp/kilroy_was_here"].execute()
```

Comment: Nice example ;-)  But maybe change it so no-one copies and pastes it and cries at you? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you need more than one command in sequence you have to use:

```
def result = [ 'ksh', '-c', 'ls -ltr;cd ..;ls -ltr;exit' ].execute() 
println result.text 

def cmds = [ 'ls -ltr', 
               'cd ..', 
                         'ls -ltr', 
                         'exit' ] 
def result = [ 'ksh', '-c', cmds.join(";") ].execute() 
println result.text
```

[Source](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/unix-cd-command-in-groovy-tp348646p348654.html)